# replace a string segment from input stream

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to receive a huge text file as an inputstream and want to convert a string segment with another string. I am strictly confused how to do it, it works well if I convert whole inputstream as a string which I don't want as some of the contents are lost. can anyone please help how to do it??
e.g.
if I have a file which has the contents "This is the test string which needs to be modified". I want to accept this string as input stream and want to modify the contents to "This is the test string which is modified" , ( by replacing 'needs to be' with is).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "This is the test string which needs to be modified";
        InputStream inpstr = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());
           //Code to do


    }
```

In this I want the output as: This is the test string which is modified

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I'd read the input stream in lines (throuh a BufferedReader) and perform substitution on a whole line before sending to output. More elegant way, subclass my WholeLineChangerInputStream from BufferedReader, override the readLine() method (applying the substitution) and use that ^^

Comment: Basically you need this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-howto/replace-strings-in-streams-arrays-files.html and then apply it to an inputstream

Answer (score 4):

If the text to be changed will always fit in one logical line, as I stated in comment, I'd go with simple Line Reading (if applyable) using something like:

```
public class InputReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String string = "This is the test string which needs to be modified";
        InputStream inpstr = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());

        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpstr));
        String buf = null;
        while ((buf = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
            // Apply regex on buf

            // build output
        }
    }
}
```

However I've always like to use inheritance so I'd define this somewhere:

```
class MyReader extends BufferedReader {
    public MyReader(Reader in)
    {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        String lBuf = super.readLine();
        // Perform matching & subst on read string
        return lBuf;
    }
}
```

And use MyReader in place of standard BufferedReader keeping the substitution hidden inside the readLine method.

Pros: substitution logic is in a specified Reader, code is pretty standard.
Cons: it hides the substitution logic to the caller (sometimes this is also a pro, still it depends on usage case)

HTH

Comment: thanks it helped.. but problem is when I have a string with some part in previous line and some part in the next line.. I face a problem with pattern matching.. I am trying to solve it out..

Comment: in that case, better use the stack machine as suggested by Nikolay. I'd keep it embedded in a custom InputStream (or BufferedReader). Can be a little triky to write, but will cover 99% of the cases.

Comment: @BigMike that solution only covers `readLine()` method, still `read()` and `read(char[])` remain with unreplaced data source. I am looking for right solution but even Apache Commons IO does not have correct implementation (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-218 abadonned in 2013).

Comment: Of course, but it was correct (in 2012) and it's still correct (2015) this way, since OP needs to perform search & replace on a full line,that would mean caching read data, implying a more sofisticated solution than a simple Reader extension.You can just override the other read methods but then you'll need to keep a window of the read data to perform the search & replace.

Answer (score 2):

May be I understood you wrong, but I think you should build a stack machine. I mean you can use a small string stack to collect text and check condition of replacement.

If just collected stack already is not matched to your condition, just flush stack to output and collect it again.

If your stack is similar with condition, carry on collecting it.

If your stack is matched your condition, make a modification and flush modified stack to output.

Comment: I found something similar and ready to use (works for me, yay!) http://tech.joshuacummings.com/2012/02/search-and-replace-input-stream.html